# regex commas not between two numbers

Tags: r, regex

I am looking for a regex for `gsub` to remove all the unwanted commas:

Data:

```
,,,,,,,12345
12345,1345,1354
123,,,,,,
12345,
,12354
```

Desired result:

```
12345
12345,1345,1354
123
12345
12354
```

This is the progress I have made so far:

`(,(?!\d+))`

Comment: Right now, [`gsub("^,+|,+$", "", x)`](https://regex101.com/r/1OLU0o/1) will work. Is it what you really need?

Comment: Yes that work, just removing comma's at the start and end does the job. If you put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to remove all leading and trailing commas.

You may do it with

```
gsub("^,+|,+$", "", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1OLU0o/1)

The regex contans two alternations, `^,+` matches 1 or more commas at the start and `,+$` matches 1+ commas at the end, and `gsub` replaces these matches with empty strings.

See R demo

```
x <- c(",,,,,,,12345","12345,1345,1354","123,,,,,,","12345,",",12354")
gsub("^,+|,+$", "", x)
## [1] "12345"           "12345,1345,1354" "123"             "12345"          
## [5] "12354"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `str_extract` from `stringr`. Thanks to greedy matching, you don't have to specify how many times a digit occurs, the longest match is automatically chosen:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(V1 = str_extract(V1, "\\d.+\\d"))
```

or if you prefer `base R`:

```
df$V1 = regmatches(df$V1, gregexpr("\\d.+\\d", df$V1))
```

**Result:**

```
               V1
1           12345
2 12345,1345,1354
3             123
4           12345
5           12354
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = ",,,,,,,12345
                12345,1345,1354
                123,,,,,,
                12345,
                ,12354")
```